# What is the best and most flexible client side javascript file uploader to user with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, upload

I would like to have a nice easy to use file upload system on my site. HTML5 drag drop would be good but the site must be responsive for mobile as well. What js libraries are true and tested for Rails 3.2.

I'm using paperclip on the backend and I've used the remotipart gem for AJAX uploads but the experience is not really perfect as I don't have progress bars available for hidden iframe uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Uploadify](http://uploadify.com)

Sample app with Rails 3.2 here https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify